# Commands like "uname -s" is not recognized in WSL when executed from poweshell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, ubuntu-18.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I need to execute the following command in WSL:

```
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

In order to execute it from powershell, i tried to run:

```
Ubuntu1804 run "sudo curl -L 'https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)' -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose"
```

But errors occur as it cannot find the value of `uname -s`  and  `uname -m`

```
uname : The term 'uname' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling
of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:107
+ ... ocker/compose/releases/download/1.23.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(u ...
+                                                             ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (uname:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

But the following command works as i manually entered the value of `uname -s` and  `uname -m` in that command.

```
 Ubuntu1804 run "sudo curl -L 'https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.23.2/docker-compose-Linux-x86_64' -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose"
```

Can anyone please help me to find when using powershell, how to incorporate the results of some commands to another command and execute it in WSL?

Also, how can i incorporate the value of environment variables like `$USER` in WSL commands and execute from powershell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your subexpressions `$( )` in the argument to the command.  PowerShell interprets these in expression mode (because of the double-quotes which allow expansion) and is looking for an executable named `uname` before passing the argument to `Ubuntu1804`.

Solutions:

- Use the stop-parser operator after `run`: `--%`
- Flip your quotes so expansion doesn't happen: `... 'sudo curl -L " ...`
- Escape the subexpressions: `` `$`(`) ``

To answer how you include environment variables in the WSL command:

```
& Ubuntu1804.exe ... $Env:USER ...
```

---

#### [`about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing?view=powershell-5.1)

#### [`about_Environment_Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-5.1)

Comment: @Thelncorrigible1 Thanks for the answer! The first option to use stop-parser operator worked for me!

Comment: But using the stop-parser operator is not working for a command that contain a pipeline character. As the official documentation says:

**The stop-parsing symbol is effective only until the next newline or pipeline character. You cannot use a continuation character to extend its effect or use a command delimiter to terminate its effect.**

In a command like `Ubuntu1804 run curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -` , `--%` can't affect the portion after `|`. But enclosing the entire command within double quotes works well! @TheIncorrigible1

Comment: Including environment variables in the WSL command by using '$Env:USER' not worked for me. I am adding what worked for me in this case as an answer here.

Comment: @AnjanaDyna If you want to use `--%` AND reference environment variables, use the `%USER%` batch syntax (since that's what it's falling back to in this case)

Answer (score 0):

For normal commands like `sudo apt-get update -y` just use stop-parsing operator as:

```
Ubuntu1804 run --% sudo apt-get update -y
```

For commands like  `curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -`  which includes pipeline characters (`|`)  , using only `--%` will not work. In such cases enclosing the command within double quotes works as:

```
 Ubuntu1804 run --% "curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -"
```

Also, avoid using usage of backslash or new line in commands when using `--%` operator. For example, instead of using like this:

```
Ubuntu1804 run --% sudo apt-get install \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    gnupg-agent \
    software-properties-common
```

Execute like:

```
Ubuntu1804 run --% sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates curl gnupg-agent software-properties-common
```

Including environment variables in the WSL command by using like `$Env:USER` doesn't worked for the command `sudo usermod -aG docker $USER`.

It is an error if i use it like this:

```
 Ubuntu1804 run sudo usermod -aG docker $Env:USER
```

or like this:

```
  Ubuntu1804 run --% sudo usermod -aG docker $Env:USER
```

What worked for me to include the environment variables of WSL in powershell commands is using the stop-parsing operator `--%` like this:

```
 Ubuntu1804 run --% sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```