# Is it possible on WSL to run git submodule update --init?

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows Subsystem for Linux on a Windows 10 machine. I have just cloned a repository from GitHub that contains several submodules. To initialize those submodules, I typically run the command:
`git submodule update --init`

However, when I do that I get an error:
`/usr/lib/git-core/git-submodule: 332: /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-setup: uname: Input/output error`

Has anyone else seen this behavior? Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try first and [upgrade Git](https://wsl-guide.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/update.html) (or [compile it from sources](https://jimfrenette.com/2018/07/git-updates-for-windows-powershell-and-wsl-ubuntu/#ubuntu)) to the latest 2.26.2.
More and more of submodule is [rewritten in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60213752/6309) (from its former bash script state), [starting from 2.16](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60267524/6309) (Q4 2017)

The [`git-sh-setup`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/e870325ee8575d5c3d7afe0ba2c9be072c692b65/git-sh-setup.sh#L334) bash script does a `case $(uname -s) in`, with `uname -s` supposed to work ([unless executed from a Powershell session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55274687/6309))
That `uname` code dates back to [commit 87bddba](https://github.com/git/git/commit/87bddba9924045e39e988d9704714db90abd5619), Git v1.6.0-rc0, Nov. 2007, 13 years ago.

Comment: I just updated git to version 2.26.2 (from 2.17.1), but unfortunately I am still seeing the same error (though it now occurs on line 333 instead of 332): /usr/lib/git-core/git-submodule: 333: /usr/lib/git-core/git-sh-setup: uname: Input/output error

Comment: Just the command `uname -s` produces the error "-bash: /bin/uname: Input/output error", but it sounds like you expected that to work. Perhaps this is the source of the error? Is this supposed to work in WSL?

Comment: @corjstout `uname -s` (in WSL) is the root of the problem (Git or no Git). It should work. What does `which uname` return? and `uname --version` and `uname --help`?

Comment: `which uname`: /bin/uname, `uname --version`: -bash: /bin/uname: Input/output error, `uname --help`: -bash: /bin/uname: Input/output error

Comment: @corjstout Did you try a shutdown/restart of WSL, as in https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4377#issuecomment-518221786?

Comment: @corjstout Or re-mounting the C disk: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4377#issuecomment-614897019

Comment: `wsl.exe --shutdown`: Invalid command line option: --shutdown. The only options are -d, -e, -u, --help. I have restarted my computer though. I also tried remounting the C disk. Nothing has changed though, uname is still not working.

Comment: @corjstout Strange. Hopefully it will work better with WSL2 and Windows 10 20H1 which should be released next month.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is due to the `git` could not find binaries in `/usr/lib/git-core/` in WSL Ubuntu. And it is fixed in WSL2 with Windows 10 version 2004 (OS Build 19041.208) or later.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Unfortunately I don't have a version of Windows 10 recent enough to run WSL2, but I'll try it out as soon as I can.